# How To Draw a Monomer on Latex

Tags: pdftex, chemfig, chemistry

I'm new to drawing chemical figures in LaTeX, so I can't really show my "attempt"

Could somebody show how to draw the monomer for starch in LaTeX? It should look something like this by the time I'm done in LaTeX[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The `chemfig` manual contians a whole section (11.3)  in how to draw glucose in different representations (such as Fisher and  Haworth projection).

Comment: Ah well, I'm under a time crunch at the moment so I can't learn to draw the figure in time.

Comment: @Lex_i: If you're in a hurry, you might possibly be better off using a regular chemical formula drawing program rather than latex. If you have a little bit of time, you might want to have a look at page 39 of the [`chemfig` manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) which offers a complete example on how to draw glucose. If this does not meet your requirements, you can ask a new question on how to adjust the given code to suit your needs.

Comment: The carbohydrates package draws glucose is various configurations with \glucose.